# My results from a postgress query statement has no values?

Tags: php, html, postgresql

I am relatively new with using postgress, so I am trying to get results without using the PDO statements. 
My code is as follows, now I successfully made a connection with the database, on execution my webpage has no results. On furthur inspection I noted that the while loop does not execute I know it is not a logical error with my query statement because I ran the same query on the database and it returned values.

I think the problem is in the while loop, but I cannot understand. This query on the database returned 43 results.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM property WHERE latitude BETWEEN " .$lat1 ." AND " .$lat2 ." AND longitude BETWEEN " .$lng1 ." AND " .$lng2; 

        $result = pg_query($db, $query); 
        if (!$result) { 
            echo "Problem with query " . $query . "<br/>"; 
            echo pg_last_error(); 
            exit(); 
        } 



        pg_result_seek($result,0);
        while($myrow = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
            echo "reached";
            printf ("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>", $myrow['p_id'], htmlspecialchars($myrow['type']), htmlspecialchars($myrow['latitude']), htmlspecialchars($myrow['longitude']));
            printf ("<br>");
```

Again to re-iterate, the results array is not empty because it does not throw an error message, I think there is an issue solely with the while statement.

Comment: Before your call to `pg_query`, add an `echo $query;` and let us know what it shows. It may be that  `lat1 > lat2` or `lng1 > lng2` ...

Answer (score -1):

Try adding qoutes(')

So:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM property WHERE latitude BETWEEN '" .$lat1 ."' AND '" .$lat2 ."' AND longitude BETWEEN '" .$lng1 ."' AND '" .$lng2 . "'";
```

Let us know if it helped

Comment: nope didnt work, and I ran the statement on the database without quotes but it still worked I also tried adding brackets, didnt work too. the webpage is completely blank and does not echo reached as well.